# Inno Setup - Adding Empty Directory Gives Doenst Exist Error

Tags: installation, directory

Iam getting "Doesnt Exist Error" While Adding Empty Directory.

I tried the following flags,but didnt succeed,can you guys please help me on the issue.

Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [Dirs] Function

[Dirs]

Name: "{app}\Example1"

Answer (score 0):

The flag **skipifsourcedoesntexist** ignores the source files/folders if they dont exist. For a list of all flags used in inno setup visit: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection

Why would you want to include an empty folder anyways?. If your intention is to install files in a particular folder you can mention them in the destdir section. For example if you want to install **a.txt** file inside a folder named **texts** you can do the following

```
[Files]
Source: "a.txt"; DestDir: "{app}\texts";
```

P.S: Note that inno setup creates the folder by default if it does not exist.